# NumberFormatException thrown when inserting to database

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

when i try to insert to my database i keep getting this error the jsp is code is.`

```
                <input type="text" name="bookz" value="${book.bookid}"/>
```

mainservlet

```
String bookz = request.getParameter("bookid");

    int book_id = Integer.parseInt(bookz);
    String operation = request.getParameter("operation");
    Book book = new Book(book_id, title, author, isbn, category_id);
    if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Add")) {
        bookDao.addbook(book);
        request.setAttribute("book", book);
```

i have a jsp page that that takes inputs form and inserts it to database

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
String bookz = request.getParameter("bookid");
```

try this

```
String bookz = request.getParameter("bookz");
```

It should work.

Since you were passing the wrong parameter name,it was returning null and Since Integer.parseInt method tried to parse it,it failed with NumberFormatException.